# How to "pull" an existing pdf into the app?

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf

I currently have an app in C#/WPF, and I have a manual on how to use it in `pdf`, and I'm thinking of adding a button that when clicked open the manual ... How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow !
Please take some time to follow the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and to learn [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions.
An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a summary of your researches would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process.Start("C:\Temp\yourname.pdf");

replace the string "C:\Temp\yourname.pdf" with the path and filename for the pdf file you want to open.

This will cause the pdf to open in your systems default pdf application.

You will need: - using System.Diagnostics;